# How can I un-taint my DKIM config after exim upgrade?

Tags: debian, exim

Debian upgrade to exim4 4.94 brings new headache: tainted variables.

I have several virtual domains handled by my exim and hence I use variable expansion to obtain DKIM domain, selector and key. In my `000_localmacros` is:

```
DKIM_CANON = relaxed
# Get the domain from the outgoing mail.
DKIM_DOMAIN = ${sg{${lc:${domain_data:$h_from:}}}{^www\.}{}}

DKIM_SELECTOR = ${lookup{DKIM_DOMAIN}lsearch{/etc/exim4/dkim/selector.map}}

# The file is based on the outgoing domain-name in the from-header.
DKIM_FILE = /etc/exim4/dkim/DKIM_DOMAIN/DKIM_SELECTOR/private.key

# If key exists then use it, if not don't.
DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY = ${if exists{DKIM_FILE}{DKIM_FILE}{0}}
```

(these variables are then used in Debian's default files `transport/30_exim4-config_remote_smtp`).

Sadly this generates:

```
2021-09-10 07:13:27.625 [28932] 1mOYqk-0007WN-8p Warning: Tainted filename '/etc/exim4/dkim/example.com/n201711/private.key'
```

Note that I did replace `$domain` already with `$domain_data` as suggested by the documentation but it does not help.

How can I fix this so I can remove my `allow_insecure_tainted_data = yes` statement?

Answer (score 4):

Love your opening line.

I had a similar problem, I was using the following macro in my main config section:

```
DKIM_DOMAIN = ${lc:${domain_data:$h_from:}}
DKIM_SELECTOR = ${lookup{$dkim_domain} lsearch {/etc/exim4/dkim/tags} {$value} {defaultdkimtag}}
```

Along with a `/etc/exim4/dkim/tags` file that looks like:

```
mydomain.org: sometag
myotherdomain.org: 12345
```

But the `DKIM_DOMAIN` result is 'tainted' because `$h_from` is set by the (potential) attacker. To untaint it you have to replace it with a known-safe lookup.

The way I did it was:

```
DKIM_DOMAIN = ${lookup{${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}} lsearch,ret=key {/etc/exim4/dkim/tags}}
```

- From the (tainted) `$h_from`...
- Extract the domain using `${domain:...}`. This will still be tainted.
- Force it to lowercase `${lc:...}`. Just 'cos. Still tainted
- Look up the lowercased tainted domain using lsearch in the tags file. Here I use the `ret=key` option, which means that the *ret*urned value from the lookup will be ["replaced with a non-tainted version of the lookup key"](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-file_and_database_lookups.html)
- So it is now untainted, and therefore does not taint subsequent use in other macros etc.

Your config was

```
DKIM_DOMAIN = ${sg{${lc:${domain_data:$h_from:}}}{^www\.}{}}
```

It looks like `${domain_data:$h_from:}` is wrong - `${domain_data:...}` is not listed as a [string expansion](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-string_expansions.html). `$domain_data` is a valid variable, but that's not what you're trying to do there - I think, like me, you're trying to extract the domain from `$h_from`. So here I think you should be using `${domain:$h_from:}` (I'm not sure what the colon at the end is, either, but I'll leave that to you)

So then you'd have:

```
DKIM_DOMAIN = ${sg{${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}}{^www\.}{}}
```

But that's still going to be tainted because you're allowing any externally provided value to be used in a filepath.

So I would suggest the following solution:

```
FROM_DOMAIN_WITHOUT_WWW = ${sg{${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}}{^www\.}{}}
DKIM_DOMAIN = ${lookup{FROM_DOMAIN_WITHOUT_WWW} lsearch,ret=key {/etc/exim4/dkim/selector.map}}
```

Or, if you don't like the extra macro:

```
DKIM_DOMAIN = ${lookup{${sg{${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}}{^www\.}{}}} lsearch,ret=key {/etc/exim4/dkim/selector.map}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution but I am not sure if it works with nested directories.

I just changed the `DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY` to:

```
DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY = ${lookup {DKIM_SELECTOR.DKIM_DOMAIN.key} dsearch,ret=full {/etc/exim4/dkim}}
```

and instead store the keys in a flat directory as `selector.domainname.key`.